# How to fix Javascript animation function?

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to move an image across the screen and have it reset back to the start position when it reaches the edge of the screen. I have/had the animation portion working but am struggling on the window borders.

My moveDown() function is working as I expect it to but when copying the code over to the moveRight() function it moves the image over ten pixels, resets and gets caught in a loop repeating that same movement.

Thanks in advance for helping and I'd love to hear any thoughts on how to clean up this code or make it more optimized.

```
    <script type = "text/javascript">
     <!--
        var imgObj = null;
        var animate ;
        var maxw = window.outerWidth + "px";
        var maxh = window.innerHeight + "px";

        function init() {
           imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
           imgObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
           imgObj.style.left = '0px'; 
           imgObj.style.top = '0px'; 
        }

        function moveRight() {
           if (imgObj.style.left > maxw) {
              imgObj.style.left = "0px";
              imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
              animate = setTimeout(moveRight,20); 
           } else{
           imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
           animate = setTimeout(moveRight,20); 
           document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = maxw;
           document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = imgObj.style.left;
           }
        }

        function moveDown() {
           if (imgObj.style.top > maxh) {
              imgObj.style.top = '0px';
              imgObj.style.top = parseInt(imgObj.style.top) + 10 + 'px';
              animate = setTimeout(moveDown,20); 
           } else{
              imgObj.style.top = parseInt(imgObj.style.top) + 10 + 'px';
              animate = setTimeout(moveDown,20);   // call moveDown in 20msec
           }
        }


        function stop() {
           location.reload();
        }

        window.onload = init;
     //-->
  </script>
```

Comment: What is the value of `window.outerWidth`?

Comment: Is there any reason for not using `window.innerWidth` instead?

Comment: I originally used window.innerWidth. It wasn't working for me so I tried using window.outerWidth instead as a test to see if that would work for me. I forgot to switch it back. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `moveDown` is also broken but you haven't noticed.

`imgObj.style.left` and `maxw` are both strings. `"11px"` is *larger than* `"1000px"`.
Perhaps `maxh` happens to be a value that works but `maxw` is not.

The solution is fairly simple: use `parseInt` and compare as numbers.

You could also use [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to avoid having to grab values from `style`. Do keep in mind that accessing `getBoundingClientRect` triggers a repaint which can make animations choppy, in that sense it's no better than accessing `.style`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated `maxw` to use `parseInt` and also put `parseInt` on the `imgObj.style.left` in the `if` block and that worked for me.

In execution I don't see how `moveDown` is broken, but I'll update the code to use `parseInt` on that as well.